# Transform Columns Into Rows for certain subsets of both columns and rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How would you transform rows into columns using my data? My current dataset looks like 'Original df' shown below, and I want it to look like the 'New df2'. Just to be clear, Session 1, matches with ADS1 and RDS1 and hence Appoint 2 corresponds to ADS2 RDS2.

Original df:

```
Name    Session1    Session2    Session1t    Session2t   ADS1    RDS1    ADS2    RDS2     

Sam     23.09.2017  24.09.2017  11:00:00     11:00:00    3        -9        6        8
Sarah   24.09.2017  27.09.2017  12:00:00     12:00:00    2        Nan       7        8
Steve   23.10.2017  31.10.2017  11:00:00     12:00:00    5         9        7        9
Mark    23.09.2017              11:00:00                 0         3        
James   23.09.2017  26.09.2017               11:00:00    4         7        1        4
```

New df:

```
Name    Sessions        Sessiontimes      ADS       RDS

Sam     23.09.2017      11:00:00           3       -9
Sam     24.09.2017      11:00:00           6        8
Sarah   24.09.2017      12:00:00           2        NaN
Sarah   27.09.2017      12:00:00           7        8
Steve   23.10.2017      11:00:00           5        9
Steve   31.10.2017      12:00:00           7        9
Mark    23.09.2017      11:00:00           0        3
James   23.09.2017                         4        7
James   26.09.2017      11:00:00           1        4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great scenario for `wide_to_long`.  However, you should first change how you store the session times, so they are easier to match with each other, and don't conflict with the other `Session` series.

---

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'Session(\d+)t', r'Time\1')

pd.wide_to_long(
  df, stubnames=['Session', 'Time', 'ADS', 'RDS'], i='Name', j='ID'
).dropna()
```

```
             Session      Time  ADS  RDS
Name  ID
Sam   1   23.09.2017  11:00:00  3.0   -9
Sarah 1   24.09.2017  12:00:00  2.0  Nan
Steve 1   23.10.2017  11:00:00  5.0    9
Mark  1   23.09.2017  11:00:00  0.0    3
Sam   2   24.09.2017  11:00:00  6.0    8
Sarah 2   27.09.2017  12:00:00  7.0    8
Steve 2   31.10.2017  12:00:00  7.0    9
James 2   26.09.2017  11:00:00  1.0    4
```

Comment: My output does not correspond to this??

Comment: Instead each session, session time, ADS has its own row? and hence the first row of data moves diagonally downloads from left to right?